# parsing it out text divided by a special character?

Tags: php

I have single field that allows the user to input different options in one string. So, 13123123|540|450

How would I parse out those three values into three variables?

Comment: Did you mean "specific" or "arbitrary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [list](http://php.net/list) to put them into three distinct variables:

```
$str = '13123123|540|450';
list($one, $two, $three) = explode('|', $str);
```

Alternatively, you can just access them via the array indicies if you wanted to:

```
$str = '13123123|540|450';
$split = explode('|', $str);
// $split[0] == 13123123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following methods:

```
$input = @$_POST["field"];

//  Method 1: An array

$options = explode ("|", $input);

/*
    The $options variable will now have the following:
    $options[0] = "13123123";
    $options[1] = "540";
    $options[2] = "450";
*/

// Method 2: Assign to different variables:

list($opt1, $opt2, $opt3) = explode ("|", $input);

/*
    The variables will now have the following:
    $opt1 = "13123123";
    $opt2 = "540";
    $opt3 = "450";
*/

// Method 3: Regular expression:

preg_match ("/(\w*)|(\w*)|(\w*)/i", $string, $matches);

/*
    The $options variable will now have the following:
    $matches[0] = "13123123";
    $matches[1] = "540";
    $matches[2] = "450";
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex based on the numbers before each `|`. So something along the lines of `[\d{8}]^\|]` for the first one and so on.